# How to show the Font Preview in a mac Application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I have to show the Font Preview of a font. For that I just Copied the character set from the font and then I showed as the Preview. This is my coding.

```
     NSString *fontName=@"aFontName";

    CFStringRef CFFontName = (CFStringRef)fontName;
    CTFontRef fontRef = CTFontCreateWithName(CFFontName, 0.0,NULL);

    NSCharacterSet *characterset = (NSCharacterSet *) CTFontCopyCharacterSet (fontRef); 
    unichar idx;
    NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]init];
    for( idx = 0; idx < 65000; idx++ )
    {
        if ([characterset characterIsMember: idx])
        {
            if ( isprint(idx) ) {
                NSString *str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",idx];
                str=[str stringByAppendingString:str2];
            }
            else {
                NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",idx];
                str=[str stringByAppendingString:str1];
            }
        }


    }
```

Then Finally in the TextView I showed the Strings from the **`str`** as Font Preview. But **str** has lot of unwanted characters(For the Hindi Language Font it is showing the English character also) . I think it is not the correct way for showing the Preview of a font. Is there is any other way for showing the font preview like **FontBook** application in mac?

Answer (score 2):

FontBook is using a private routine to get a sample string from the font. If private routines are okay for your app, then you can simply define:

```
CFStringRef CTFontCopySampleString(CTFontRef font, int options);
```

and call like:

```
NSString* sample = (NSString *) CTFontCopySampleString(fontRef, 0);
```

and you'll get the same string as FontBook shows.

Comment: thank you sir... It worked perfectly.. But is there is any way for getting the sample string like this without using the private routines?

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a public routine for doing this.

Comment: ok thank you sir..... If you don't mind may I know where I will get this type of private routines just for studying purpose?